# Double from long bits

Tags: c++, gcc, double, long-integer

I have an `unsigned long long` (or `uint64_t`) value and want to convert it to a `double`. The double shall have the same bit pattern as the `long` value. This way I can set the bits of the double "by hand".

```
unsigned long long bits = 1ULL;
double result = /* some magic here */ bits;
```

I am looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this? Having a hard time parsing a *question* out of this.

Comment: In C99, you can legally do this via a union. In C++, you'd have to do it using a `memcpy()`.

Comment: If'n yer feelin' like bein' a dangerous badboy, yer tool o' choice would be somethin' like a [this here cast, young feller.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17644642/cowboy_cast.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The portable way to do this is with `memcpy` (you may also be able to conditionally do it with `reinterpret_cast` or a union, but those aren't certain to be portable because they violate the letter of the strict-alias rules):

```
// First, static assert that the sizes are the same
memcpy(&result, &bits, sizeof(bits));
```

But before you do make sure you know exactly what you're doing and what floating point representation is being used (although IEEE754 is a popular/common choice). You'll want to avoid all kinds of problem values like infinity, NaN, and denormal numbers.

Comment: I believe the standard actually allows you to "reinterpret_cast<double&>(bits)" in this case, as both types are standard-layout, assuming double doesn't require a more strict alignment.

Answer (score 6):

Beware of `union` and `reinterpret_cast<double*>(&bits)`, for both of these methods are UB. Pretty much all you can do is memcpy.

Comment: @Saksham Yes, by "UB" he means undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

since C++ 20 we have `std::bit_cast()` to to such conversions

example:

```
double d = 1.5;
uint64_t i = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(d); //use the same bits in an integer
double dd = std::bit_cast<double>(i); //back to floating point again
```

Answer (score -3):

The following uses a void pointer.

```
unsigned long long bits = 1ULL;
void* tempPtr=(void*)&bits;
double result = *(double*)tempPtr;
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour- strict aliasing violation. This is the same as dasblinkenlight's answer but with a completely pointless temporary.

Comment: I was aware that my answer is the same as dasblinkenlight's, but since it uses a completely different syntax it appears to be a different method. Thus, I felt it was appropriate to post as an answer to the question. And as for the fact that it is undefined behavior, I do not know of one compiler or system that is incapable of handlng this (provided both variables are the same size).

Comment: The addition of the temporary is utterly meaningless, the method is identical. Also, it's undefined behaviour, and that's that.