# C++: Why is the value assignment interpretation always int?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, floating-point-precision, interpretation

I'd like to assign a value to a variable like this:

```
double var = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

As a result `var` gets the value 65535.0 assigned. Since the compiler assumes a 64bit target system the number literal (i.e. all respective 32 bits) is interpreted significand precision bits. However, since `0xFFFF FFFF` is just a notation for a bit pattern, without any hint about the representation, it could be quite differently interpreted w.r.t. becoming a floating point value. Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate this fixed interpretation of the value. In other words, give a hint about the desired representation. (Maybe someone could also point me to part in the standard where this implicit interpretation is defined).

So far, the default precision interpretation on my system seems to be

**(int)0xFFFFFFFF x 10<sup>0</sup>**.

[image]
Only the fraction field is getting filled<sup>1</sup>.

So maybe (here: for 16 bit cross-compilation) I want it to be a different representation like:

**(int)0xFFFFFF x 10<sup>(int)0xFF</sup>**

(ignoring the sign bit for a moment).

Thus my question: How can I force a custom double interpretation of the hex literal notation?

---

<sup>1 Even when my hex literal would be `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF` the value is only interpreted as the fraction part - so clearly, bits should be used for exponent and sign field. But it seems the literal gets just cut off.</sup>

Comment: And what is your real question (XY-problem) ?

Comment: 0xffff is the same as 65535.

Comment: @[Dieter Lücking](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2249683/dieter-l%c3%bccking) See update: How can I force double interpretation of the hex notation?

Comment: `How can I force double interpretation of the hex notation`  What's wrong with just saying `double var = 65535.0;`

Comment: It's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521638/exact-binary-representation-of-a-double

Comment: @[molbdnilo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) No that's what I'm trying to avoid and that's what seems to be the default standard.

Comment: @Kris this doesn't compile

Comment: @JimMcAdams Writing 0xffff is literally the same as writing 65535. The notation makes no difference.

Comment: I think you're asking about hexadecimal floating point literals ( http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/06/perl-v5-22-adds-hexadecimal-floating-point-literals/ ), which exist in Perl and C99, but I don't know if they're in C++.

Comment: "... since casting won't work for obvious reasons" - with how your question is phrased, those reasons are anything-but-obvious. Dieter's comment holds much weight. What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve? I suspect Ivan's link holds much relevance, but without more specifics from you it is difficult to tell.

Comment: What is your idea of a floating point interpretation of 0xffff ?

Comment: @[May Lybbert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/10593/max-lybbert) Thanks, that's an interesting article and yes, I'm looking for the respective implementation in C++. ;)

Comment: @[WhozCraig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig) What I meant was that the compiler interprets all the bits of `0xFF..` before it is checking on any other conversion wrapped around it. So no matter what I put around it, it will always do its thing first. Seemed obvious for me at least. Hope the question makes now more sense.

Comment: @all I read the other linked threads. It seems that the cause of our problems is indeed the same but the resulting questions aren't. So, I'm not really sure if it's a doublicate. Gotta read them again probably. ;P

Comment: [c++ portable conversion of long to double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843704/995714), [Double from long bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17409162/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable way to serialize float as 32-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416682/portable-way-to-serialize-float-as-32-bit-integer)

Answer (score 3):

> *"I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate this interpretation."*

Yes, you can use a `reinterpret_cast<double&>` via address, to force type (re-)interpretation from a certain bit pattern in memory.

> *"Thus my question: How can I force double interpretation of the hex notation?"*

You can also use a union, to make it clearer:

```
union uint64_2_double {
    uint64_t bits;
    double dValue;
};

uint64_2_double x;
x.bits = 0x000000000000FFFF;

std::cout << x.dValue << std::endl;
```

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior?

Comment: @AntonSavin Not more, or less than using a  reinterpret_cast<>, actually.

Comment: In GCC an attempt to reinterpret_cast<double>(unsigned long) gives a hard compile error, same in Clang.

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a direct way to initialize a `double` variable with an hexadecimal pattern, the c-style cast is equivalent to a C++ `static_cast` and the `reinterpret_cast` will complain it can't perform the conversion.  I will give you two options, one simple solution but that will not initialize directly the variable, and a complicated one.  You can do the following:

`double var;`
`*reinterpret_cast<long *>(&var) = 0xFFFF`;

Note: watch out that I would expect you to want to initialize all 64 bits of the `double`, your constant 0xFFFF seems small, it gives 3.23786e-319

A literal value that begins with 0x is an hexadecimal number of type unsigned int.  You should use the suffix ul to make it a literal of unsigned long, which in most architectures will mean a 64 bit unsigned; or, `#include <stdint.h>` and do for example `uint64_t(0xABCDFE13)`

Now for the complicated stuff:  In old C++ you can program a function that converts the integral constant to a double, but it won't be `constexpr`.

In `constexpr` functions you can't make `reinterpret_cast`.  Then, your only choice to make a constexpr converter to double is to use an union in the middle, for example:

```
struct longOrDouble {
    union {
        unsigned long asLong;
        double asDouble;
    };
    constexpr longOrDouble(unsigned long v) noexcept: asLong(v) {}
};

constexpr double toDouble(long v) { return longOrDouble(v).asDouble; }
```

This is a bit complicated, but this answers your question.  Now, you can write:
`double var = toDouble(0xFFFF)`
And this will insert the given binary pattern into the double.

Using `union` to write to one member and read from another is undefined behavior in C++, there is an excellent question and excellent answers on this right here:
[Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't specify the in-memory representation for `double`, moreover, it doesn't even specify the in-memory representation of integer types (and it can really be different on systems with different endings). So if you want to interpret bytes `0xFF`, `0xFF` as a `double`, you can do something like:

```
uint8_t bytes[sizeof(double)] = {0xFF, 0xFF};
double var;
memcpy(&var, bytes, sizeof(double));
```

Note that using unions or `reinterpret_cast`ing pointers is, strictly speaking, undefined behavior, though in practice also works.

Comment: Referring to EdMaster's answer, why is doing this using Unions undefined behavior?

Comment: @Chuu because you can't just write to one member of a union and read from another. It's technically UB though works in practice as I said.

Comment: @Chuu Using unions writing from one side and looking from the other might be undefined behavior, I don't know, but attempting to look at a bit pattern as a `double` is.
I think the question was of a practical nature, I am giving practical answers.
Undefined behavior or not, to write to one side of the union and look at it from another is a legitimate programming technique, if your platform allows it.
I am not sure it is undefined behavior, it might be implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @AntonSavin thanks for pointing out the UB nature of the union.
I found an excellent question and also excellent answers on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined